# Codeigniter Error On Windows Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, permissions

I have an Error Like this:

```
Type: Exception

Message: Session: Configured save path 'C:\Windows\TEMP' is not writable by the PHP process.
```

Can anyone tell me: these error are appearing on website codeigniter http://camelianmultiservices.co.in/index.php

Comment: It seems that  it  haven't right permission to make sessions directory

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a concise and as detailed answer as I would like, but it should explain the basics.

You need to configure $config['sess_save_path'] to be a folder within your websites document root. It cannot write anywhere...

> save path 'C:\Windows\TEMP' is not writable by the PHP process

The above error means - PHP cannot write there. If you put this up on a webserver (for instance, running apache on a linux box ) - Where will C:\Windows\TEMP be???? It has to reside within the folders the webserver has access to.

So one way is to create a folder called sessions ( you can name it whatever you like ) under your application folder.

Set the sess_save_path to suit...

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'sessions';
```

in the above that would mean having the sessions folder under the application folder. i.e `application/sessions`

AND Make sure that this folder is writeable.
If under linux, from the application folder in a terminal , type

```
chmod 770 sessions
```

This gives Owner and Group Full Access - while - Everyone else gets diddley squat (ie. no access at all )

If you are worried about security, you can create the folder as far up as your document root with the correct permissions and the correct path supplied.

Comment: Hi tim, This is not my question but I was wondering 0777 vs 0700 for permission for sessions.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 - It should be more like 0770 maybe - So the Group gets full access. Just checked it and that works... Thanks for the - "Did I really test it out properly" memory jog.