# How to use Session Library in codeigniter 4, i get some error when use the session library

Tags: session, codeigniter-4

I want to use session library in codeigniter 4,i read the codeigniter 4 documentation.
I set the session library in constructor function, but i get error like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9hGi.png)

I have set up session library like this :

```
class Login extends BaseController
{
    protected $authModel;
    protected $session;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
        $this->session->start();
        $this->authModel = new AuthModel();
    }
```

and I set the session value on my controler like this :

```
  $userData = [
                'username'  => $result['result']['username'],
                'role_id'     => $result['result']['role_id'],
            ];

            $this->session->set($userData); // setting session data
            dd($this->session->get("username"));
```

But that's not working
Please help me who knows the solution

Comment: [Session: Configured save path 'C:\Windows\Temp' is not writable by the PHP process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472209/session-configured-save-path-c-windows-temp-is-not-writable-by-the-php-proce)

Comment: Check if the `writable` folder found at your application's root has *'read-write-execute'* rights. If that isn't the case, then assign the relevant rights.

Comment: [Codeigniter Error On Windows Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620662/codeigniter-error-on-windows-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `.env` file and set:

```
app.sessionSavePath = '/tmp/ci4_session'
```